# ModuleNotFoundError on import

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, path, modulenotfounderror

I have a project with this structure:

[image: structure]

when I try to import a function from file_A into file_B:

```
from app_1.file_A import function
```

I get an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app_1'
```

What is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) about how import system works.

Comment: @sudden_appearance I can't find the answer to my question in the documentation. Could you give me a short answer?

Comment: You are most likely starting your script not from project root folder